# Looking for a cleaner way of filtering a data.table based on value differences within a multi-variable group

Tags: r, data.table

I was working on a problem where I had two grouping variables and one value.  I only to keep the rows were at least two of the values in the group are close to each other in value. In the example I wanted groups that had one set of values within 10 of each other.

Below is what I initially tried, and something about making a flag variable made me feel like I was doing it in some roundabout way, and I just wanted to know if there's a cleaner more intended way to do something like this in data.table. Thank you!

x and y are the categories, z is the value.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)


dt <- data.table(
  x = sample(LETTERS, 1000, T),
  y = sample(letters, 1000, T),
  z = sample(100, 1000, T),
  key = tail(letters, 3)
)

dt <- unique(dt)
dt <- dt[dt[, .(flag = any(diff(z) <= 11)), .(x, y)], on = c("x", "y")][(flag)]
dt[, flag := NULL]
dt
```

Comment: You can apply aggregations straight to the data e.g. `dt[, flag := any(diff(z) <= 11), by=.(x,y)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
res <- dt[, if (.N > 1L && min(diff(z)) <= 11) .SD, by=.(x, y)]
```

I used `min` instead of `any` since I guess it leads to fewer computations.

I added the `.N > 1L` condition since you need to think about how to handle the single row case (where diff is NA). You could do

- `.N > 1L &&` to drop those cases
- `.N == 1L ||` to keep them

> I just wanted to know if there's a cleaner more intended way to do something like this in data.table

I think a `having=` syntax would be convenient for this. It's currently [a feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788).

---

Input data (since OP overwrites it):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(
  x = sample(LETTERS, 1000, T),
  y = sample(letters, 1000, T),
  z = sample(100, 1000, T),
  key = tail(letters, 3)
)
dt <- unique(dt)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.I` with an `if` to determine whether to include each group (here `want` matches your final `dt`)

```
dt <- unique(dt)
want <- dt[dt[, if(any(diff(z) <= 11)) .I, .(x, y)]$V1]
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar but not as clean: `dt[dt[, rep(any(diff(z) <= 11), .N), .(x,y)]$V1]`